# modify code in php code from within the same file

Tags: php, arrays

i have a php file that one of the rows is array as shown:

```
$settings = array('path' => '/Users/eli/', // define the path by unix syntax.
    'username' => 'elibyy',
    'password' => 'elibyy',
    'show_mime' => 1,
    'show_actions' => 1
);
```

i want to give the user ability to edit this settings via a form and update them within the php file.

so after the update the script file will contain a new array with the posted settings

i don't want to use database or other files.

is this a good approach or should i create settings file?

Comment: OK, did you give the ole college try?

Comment: You really should separate configuration settings from code: self modifying code is a really bad approach to this problem

Comment: We don't just write code for people when they get a crazy idea and want it done, please try some stuff yourself and if you get stuck with a specific problem then post on SO.

Comment: @DrCord i know, i'm not looking for a code i want to understand the idea is it good or not

Comment: no, it's a terrible idea. Use a database or something...

Comment: @elibyy no its a terrible idea, Config files and databases exist for a reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to do this kind of action i suggest that you check [the file handling](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file.asp) part of php and deal with the file that has the array as a simple flat text file